# [pine-script], how can i create ALERT, of multiple "alertcondition" , on MULTIPLE security ()

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, quantitative-finance

in pine-script (trading view).
how can i create an Alert. where Multiple "alertcondition" are activated on **multiple** securities.
for example:

// Code for alert with price above 250
priceAlert = (close > 250)

alertcondition(condition=priceAlert,
message="Price is above $250")

AND

// Code an alert with price below 75
priceAlert = (close < 75)

alertcondition(condition=priceAlert,
message="Price is below $75")

---

will be applied to **multiple** security():

SMN() **AND** VXX() **AND** spxs() etc.

---

***alerting, only when all alertconditions, applied on *all* securities().

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a one-to-one relationship between `alertcondition()` calls and running alerts on your chart. See the [Pine usrman on alerts](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Alerts.html#) for an explanation of how you can build a compound condition on one `alertcondition()` call.

Using the new `alert()` function would probably easier, as you can aggregate all `alert()` call events in your script in one alert on your chart, and use dynamic messages for your alerts. The same usrman page explains how to use `alert()` in a few different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

To make an alert condition fire when multiple conditions of our alert setup are true, we use `and` operator.

```
study(title="Multiple alert criteria - example 1", overlay=false)

rsiValue = rsi(close, 12)

// Set up alert
alertcondition(condition=
     (rsiValue > 50) and (close > ema(close, 25)),
     message="RSI > 50 with EMA uptrend")
```